# SQLAlchemy IN clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, in-clause

I'm trying to do this query in sqlalchemy

```
SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE id IN (123, 456)
```

I would like to bind the list `[123, 456]` at execution time.

Answer (score 599, accepted):

How about

```
session.query(MyUserClass).filter(MyUserClass.id.in_((123,456))).all()
```

**edit**: Without the ORM, it would be

```
session.execute(
    select(
        [MyUserTable.c.id, MyUserTable.c.name], 
        MyUserTable.c.id.in_((123, 456))
    )
).fetchall()
```

[`select()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.select) takes two parameters, the first one is a list of fields to retrieve, the second one is the `where` condition. You can access all fields on a table object via the `c` (or `columns`) property.

Answer (score 202):

Assuming you use the declarative style (i.e. ORM classes), it is pretty easy:

```
query = db_session.query(User.id, User.name).filter(User.id.in_([123,456]))
results = query.all()
```

`db_session` is your database session here, while `User` is the ORM class with `__tablename__` equal to `"users"`.

Comment: Use `~` (`~User.id.in_([123,456])`) or `not_` from `sqlalchemy.sql.expression` (`not_(User.id.in_([123,456]))`).

Comment: Here is a [link to the doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators).

Answer (score 62):

An alternative way is using raw SQL mode with SQLAlchemy, I use SQLAlchemy 0.9.8, python 2.7, MySQL 5.X, and MySQL-Python as connector, in this case, a tuple is needed. My code listed below:

```
id_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # in most case we have an integer list or set
s = text('SELECT id, content FROM myTable WHERE id IN :id_list')
conn = engine.connect() # get a mysql connection
rs = conn.execute(s, id_list=tuple(id_list)).fetchall()
```

Hope everything works for you.

Comment: If you use raw SQL for such simple queries you are better of using psycopg2 or other connector directly.

Comment: Update is not working

Answer (score 17):

Just wanted to share my solution using sqlalchemy and pandas in python 3. Perhaps, one would find it useful.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd
engine = sa.create_engine("postgresql://postgres:my_password@my_host:my_port/my_db")
values = [val1,val2,val3]   
query = sa.text(""" 
                SELECT *
                FROM my_table
                WHERE col1 IN :values; 
""")
query = query.bindparams(values=tuple(values))
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
```

Comment: _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type tuple cannot be converted

Comment: My problem is that it's doing 'ARRAY[]'
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: operator does not exist: bigint = integer[]
LINE 4:         WHERE ancestor_concept_id IN(ARRAY[44810261,4225055,...

Answer (score 11):

With the expression API, which based on the comments is what this question is asking for, you can use the `in_` method of the relevant column.

To query

```
SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE id in (123,456)
```

use

```
myList = [123, 456]
select = sqlalchemy.sql.select([user_table.c.id, user_table.c.name], user_table.c.id.in_(myList))
result = conn.execute(select)
for row in result:
    process(row)
```

This assumes that `user_table` and `conn` have been defined appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

Or maybe use .in_(list), similar to what @Carl has already suggested
as

```
 stmt = select(
        id,
         name
      ).where(
        id.in_(idlist),
      )
```

Complete code assuming you have the data model in User class:

```
def fetch_name_ids(engine, idlist):
    # create an empty dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    try:
        # create session with engine
        session = Session(engine, future=True)
         stmt = select(
            User.id,
            User.name
          ).where(
            User.id.in_(idlist),
          )
        data = session.execute(stmt)

        df = pd.DataFrame(data.all())
        if len(df) > 0:
            df.columns = data.keys()
        else:
            columns = data.keys()
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        error = str(e.__dict__['orig'])
        session.rollback()
        raise error
     else:

        session.commit()
     finally:

        engine.dispose()
        session.close()


      return df
```

Answer (score -1):

Some people think it is unsafe because of SQL Injection:

But this is only working with Native Query:

This question posted a solution to the select query, unfortunately, it is not working for the `update` query. Using this solution would help even in the `select` conditions.

**Update Query Solution:**

```
id_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # in most cases we have an integer list or set
query = 'update myTable set content = 1 WHERE id IN {id_list}'.format(id_list=tuple(id_list))
conn.execute(query)
```

**Note**: Use a **tuple** instead of a list.

Comment: Some people might not find this safe because of sql injection, but this is the only thing I could get to work. For sql injection protection, the within my function I did the equivalent of `id_list = [int(x) for x in id_list]` just in case a string was passed, so python will throw an error in that case

Comment: Building the query as a string defeats the whole purpose of using SQLAlchemy in the first place. Instead use something like `update(myTable).values(content=1).where(myTable.c.id.in_(id_list))` (using SQLAlchemy Core - remove the `.c` if myTable is an ORM model)

Answer (score -3):

Just an addition to the answers above.

If you want to execute a SQL with an "IN" statement you could do this:

```
ids_list = [1,2,3]
query = "SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE id IN %s" 
args = [(ids_list,)] # Don't forget the "comma", to force the tuple
conn.execute(query, args)
```

Two points:

- There is no need for Parenthesis for the IN statement(like "... IN(%s) "), just put "...IN %s"
- Force the list of your ids to be one element of a tuple. Don't forget the " , " : (ids_list,)

**EDIT**
Watch out that if the length of list is one or zero this will raise an error!

Comment: I think you should do `args = [(tuple(ids_list),)]`, please double check.

Comment: The OP is asking how to do this in sqlalchemy, not using raw dbapi call...

Comment: This does not work with a single item list as it produces `(item, )` and it's incorrect in SQL