# Python: How to put user define varibales correctly for MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am an app that will get user stocklist that save and use it to query the data from MySQL. Since it is user define, I am not sure how many stocks in the stocklist by user. I know I need to put :params, just like %s used in MySQLdb. However, I get error for

```
call = db.session.execute(query,{placeholders:stockList})
```

What is the correct format to query for multiple user define input?

```
    from flask import Flask,jsonify,abort,make_response,request,render_template
    from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299

    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    @app.route('/watchlist', methods=['GET'])
    def watch():
        #stockList = ['msft','APPLE']
        stockList = request.args['stockList'].split(',')
        if len(stockList)>0:
            placeholders = ','.join([':param'] * len(stockList))
            query = 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN ({})'.format(placeholders)
            try:
                call = db.session.execute(query,{placeholders:stockList})
                f = call.fetchall()
            except Exception:
                return 'Error: unable to fetch items'
        else:
            return "No stock in stockList"
         return jsonify({'Stock': f})
```

The error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 149, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 978, in execute
    clause, params or {})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 720, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 317, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 817, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 884, in _execute_context
    None, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1108, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 174, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=exc_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 167, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 880, in _execute_context
    context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 550, in _init_compiled
    grp, m in enumerate(parameters)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 550, in <listcomp>
    grp, m in enumerate(parameters)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 453, in construct_params
    % bindparam.key)
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: A value is required for bind parameter 'param' (original cause: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: A value is requi
red for bind parameter 'param') 'SELECT * FROM KLSE WHERE Stock IN (%(param)s,%(param)s)' [{':param,:param': ['msft', 'APPLE']}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlalchemy in clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause)

Comment: No, I am not using orm.Also, my input is user define