# session.execute() IN operator of SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have one problem when i try to execute that simple request :

```
params['_filter_items'] = (12345)

sql = """ SELECT * FROM items
          WHERE items.items IN %(_filter_items)s"""
# session is a db session of sqlAlchemy
query = session.execute(sql % params)
```

it will generate :

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE items.items IN 12345
```

without ()
when i have more than one item it's ok;
i can touch the request; but i was wondered if there are another way to resolve it.

Comment: `12345` supposed to be a string or integer?

Comment: also `(12345)` is the same as `12345`, parentheses are redundant, if you want to generate single element tuple you should write `(12345,)` (comma added)

Comment: integer it s primary key of the table

Comment: and finally: you should avoid inserting of your parameters with `%`, pass them as argument to `execute` like `session.execute(sql, params)`

Comment: thanks I already try it but it doesn't work in PosgreSQL. items.item_id IN (142661089,) ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near ")" exactly in comma

Comment: btw why are you not using ORM features and executing raw SQL?

Comment: indeed , you are right , the request is an update and it does many things with more than 40 lines.  i will use ORM  in the next time =))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146243/discussion-between-anouar-mokhtari-and-azat-ibrakov).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- this object

  ```
  (12345)
  ```

  is the same as

  ```
  12345
  ```

  but it looks like you need `tuple` with single element `12345`, it can be done with comma

  ```
  (12345,)
  ```
- we should avoid inserting of parameters by ourselves:

  ```
  session.execute(sql % params)
  ```

  let's delegate this work to `SQLAlchemy` & database drivers and pass parameters as argument to `execute`:

  ```
  session.execute(sql, params)
  ```

try

```
params['_filter_items'] = (12345,)

sql = """ SELECT * FROM items
          WHERE items.items IN %(_filter_items)s"""
# session is a db session of sqlAlchemy
query = session.execute(sql, params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Line of code `params['_filter_items'] = (12345)` resolves by Python interpreter into `params['_filter_items'] = 12345`. It means in your code `(12345)` it is `int`, not a `tuple`. To use a tuple you have to write `params['_filter_items'] = (12345, )`.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this [SQLAlchemy in clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause) for a more secure way of doing this.