# how to pass variable with in operator in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In sql commed, where condition i'm using in operator along with a variable, now i've to pass value in this variable, what would be right syntax for this:

```
 select col1 from testtable where col2 in :testval
```

mysql version 5.1

Comment: What programming language/environment? Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Parametrised SQL only works on single values. Use this:

```
values = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
variables = { "var%d" % i: value for i, value in enumerate(values) }
placeholders = ", ".join(":%s" % var for var in variables.keys())
sql = "select col1 from testtable where col2 in (" + placeholders + ")"
```

You can then use `sql` with the `variables` bindings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ORM library for a higher-level access instead of plain SQL.

For example (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8603129/196206):

```
session.query(MyUserClass).filter(MyUserClass.id.in_((123,456))).all()

# alternative - without the ORM part, just query builder:

session.execute(
    select(
        [MyUserTable.c.id, MyUserTable.c.name], 
        MyUserTable.c.id.in_((123, 456))
    )
).fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like : select col1 from testtable where col2 in (var1, var2, ...)

Sample

Table Name : Test

Id  Name          Roll_No
1  R. Nikhil           34
2  Ashish Rao      25
3    Joseph             45
4    Mohammed               35
5    Jatin Gupta                 39

Mysql Query : select Name from Test where Roll_No IN (25, 35, 45);

and the result will be :

Ashish Rao
 Joseph
 Mohammed