# Flask SQLAlchemy: Selecting all rows with IDs from array

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy and I have a few tables from a database.

I'm trying to select all the rows with a specific id, to run a function. Right now I'm doing it using an if statement like this:

```
IDs = [1,2,3,4]
for id in IDs:
    data = Data.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    data.somefunction()
```

This does not seem very optimized, as I have to call the database for every id. I was wondering if there was a way to use Flask-SQLAlchemy to do a single query that returns all the rows from the database, and then I can run my function for every row and `commit()` at the end?

Comment: Use IN https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause to fetch all matching data with a single query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN:

```
DataResults = Data.query.filter(Data.id.in_(IDs)).all()
```

and for good measure, NOT IN:

```
DataResults = Data.query.filter(~Data.id.in_(IDs)).all()
```