# Using SQLAlchemy, can I join a Python object (i.e. a list) within a Query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Assuming I have a Postgres-DB table looking like this (with with many more rows):

```
|------|-------|
|col1  |col 2  |
|------|-------|
|a1    |10     |
|a2    |55     |
|a3    |24     |
|------|-------|
```

And a List in Python with Tuples looking like this:

```
|------|-------|
|a1    |1      |
|a3    |2      |
|------|-------|
```

During runtime I now want to (inner) join the table with the list without having to persist the list as a DB object.

What does work, is to filter using the list and SQLAlchemys `.in_` operator.

However when I try `db.query(Table).join(list)` I get this error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable: No inspection system is available for object of type

Of course a workaround would be to first fetch all elements from the db using the filter operator and then using python for the join...but it feels like there should be a

Comment: What exactly you want to join/filter by?

Comment: By the column "col1" and the first element of the Tuple for each row in the list

Comment: So you only want to get the rows from database, where col1 matches tuple[0]?

Comment: Not quite: I want to filter col1 by each first element in the list AND then interact with both, e.g. by adding each second element in the list to col2.

Comment: Define 'adding' please. Like for col1 it has to become 11?

Comment: @MikhailBeliansky exactly, yes

Comment: Ok, I'll modify the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you want to only get the rows where `col1 == tuple[0]`, you can use the sqlalchemy `filter` and `in_` operators:

```py
tuples_list = [('a1', 1), ('a3', 2)]

search_dict = dict(tuples_list)  # Convert to dict 

res = db.query(Table).filter(Table.col1.in_(search_dict.keys())).all()

for instance in res:
    instance.col2 = instance.col2 + search_dict[instance.col1]
```

There's also a detailed example without using the ORM here: 
[SQLAlchemy IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause)

Comment: Thanks, great hint but not quite what I'm looking for. As I already mentioned in the question: "What does work, is to filter using the list and SQLAlchemys .in_ operator."

Comment: Modified the answer, please try it out.