# SqlAlchemy: Joining a Python List to a Table

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, outer-join

**Similar Question**: [Using SQLAlchemy, can I join a Python object (i.e. a list) within a Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426934/using-sqlalchemy-can-i-join-a-python-object-i-e-a-list-within-a-query) - however, this question involves a simpler use of a Python list that could be reworked into a `filter`, which doesn't seem to apply here.

I have a 4 column table `X` (columns A,B,C,D) in my database, and two lists (a,b) of the same length in Python.

For each pair of values `(x,y)` in `zip(a,b)`, I want to find the value of `D` corresponding to the row with the smallest value of `C` such that the value of column `A` is x and the value of column `B` is y. And if such a row doesn't exist, I want to find `None/NULL`.

If `Y=list(zip(a,b))` was a two column (A,B) table in our Postgres database, we could find the answer very easily as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (Y.A, Y.B) X.D
FROM Y 
    LEFT JOIN X 
        ON Y.A=X.A
        AND Y.B=X.B 
ORDER BY X.C
```

How would I do this in SqlAlchemy?

Comment: Could you explain two list (a, b)? Are they indepent list like "a=[elementn, elementp,...], b = [elementk, elementl,...]" and you are combining them or they are just elements and you are binding them with zip? Maybe removing "two lists" and putting tuple instead would be better?

Comment: Yes, they are independent lists of the same length. I avoided using the word tuple since it doesn't imply binary tuple.