# How to do WHERE IN with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Here is what I'm trying to do. The database is Postgres.

numbers is a Python `set()` or some other iterable.

```
session.execute(table.update().\
                        where(func.substring(table.c.number,1 ,5) in numbers).\
                        values(provider="testprovider")
```

The problem with this is that `in numbers` doesn't seem to work. It will work for a single number if I do something like `where(func.substring(table.c.number,1, 5)== '12345')`

I've googled a lot on how to do `WHERE IN` with sqlalchemy, but all of them are with a SELECT query or do use the .in_() function on the column itself. For example this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause)

The [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators) also says the .in_() only works on the columns.

So, I don't really know how to proceed here. How can I write this expression?

Answer (score 0):

Ah nevermind, although the documentation doesn't say it, I can use the .in_() function on the result of func.substring.

So

```
where(func.substring(table.c.number, 1, 5).in_(numbers))
```

worked.