# Error with SQLAlchemy when query by list with "in_"

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I keep receiving the error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object 1 is not legal as a SQL literal value` when executing this query:

```
cat_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_cats = Category.query.filter(Category.id.in_(cat_list)).all()
```

My model:

```
class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
```

I have also tried

```
my_cats = db.session.query(Category).filter(Category.id.in_(cat_list)).all()
my_cats = Category.query.where(Category.id.in_(cat_list)).all()
```

It is the same error on all of them.
Question:

1. What is Object 1 referring to? "Category" or "Category.id" or my cat_list?
2. How do I fix this error?

EDIT:
I did some further work and when I make my list via a for loop and then print:

```
print(cat_list_fromloop)
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(cat_list)
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(type(cat_list_fromloop))
>> <class 'list'>
print(type(cat_list))
>> <class 'list'>
if cat_list == cat_listfromloop:
    print("same")
else:
    print("not same")
>> not same
```

So this suggests that how I am making my list is probably what is causing the issue.  I am doing this via:

```
template = Template.query.filter_by(id=int(form.template.data)).first()
cat_listfromloop = []
for val in template.categories:
    cat_listfromloop.append(val)
```

I think it failing the equality check is a hint, but still don't understand why.

Edit 2: I got it to work after I checked type of each item in list.  I needed to make sure it was an int.

```
template = Template.query.filter_by(id=int(form.template.data)).first()
cat_listfromloop = []
for val in template.categories:
    cat_listfromloop.append(int(val.id))
```

Comment: Is `Object 1 is not legal as a SQL literal value` _literally_ the error message you receive, or do you get soething like `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object <Foo object at 0x7fa417a3b400> is not legal as a SQL literal value`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, it is the `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Object 1 is not legal as a SQL literal value`.  See the edit above.  When I manually make the list with hardcoded values it works.  When I make it via a loop, it fails.  When I check the type() of each list I get `<class 'list'>`. So, it must be something with how I am creating the list (see last code block in Edit

Comment: It looks like you've solved your issue, but here's a link that provides some background information about the error message: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_11.html#specific-checks-added-for-passing-mapped-classes-instances-as-sql-literals

Answer (score 2):

Try making catlist a tuple:

```
cat_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
cat_list = tuple(cat_list)
```

There's more answers here [SQLAlchemy IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause), but I think this might already solve your problem.

Comment: You probably mean: tuple((1, 2, 3))

Tuple takes only 1 argument

Comment: yes, a common mistake, I meant to use the cat_list as the input for the tuple, like so:  cat_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]      tuple(cat_list)