# filter by mutiple arguement coma value flask sqlalchemy postgresql

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am receiving a get request something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/stockList?name=a,b,c,
```

All i want is filter by those coma value from database.Something like this:

```
name = request.args.get('name', None)
connection = db.engine.connect(close_with_result=True)

sql = text("""select * from stockstatus where name='a' or name='b' or name='c'""")
connection.execute(sql)
connection.close()
```

This is how table looks like:

```
--  id |  name  |
-- ----+---------
--  1  | a       | 
--  2  | b       |
--  3  | c      | 
--  4  | d      | 
--  5  | e      |
```

I only want a,b,c value mentioned in the get argument How can i filter by those coma value in arguement flask?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parameters to `text` method:

```
name = request.args.get('name')
if name:
   names = name.split(',')
else:
   names = []
connection = db.engine.connect(close_with_result=True)

sql = text("""select * from stockstatus where name IN :names""", names=tuple(names))
connection.execute(sql)
connection.close()
```

This topic can be helpful: [SQLAlchemy IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do something like this:

```
@app.route('/stockList/<a>/<b>/<c>')
def stockList(a=None, b=None, c=None):
```

This method should be safer.

Comment: I would not recommend making public API dependendent on set of parameters. What if there would be 'd' param? You have to change your endpoint...and you are not backward compatible

Comment: If he doesn't sanitize his parameter well he'll be in more trouble than compatibility issues.

Comment: But he can sanitize param from querystring