# How to get users from list of IDs in Flask

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, filter

I am trying to create variable of users whose ID is in list but i dont know how. This is what I tried but it doesnt work. Does someone know how to filter it correctly?

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
users = Users.query.filter(Users.id in list)
```

Comment: Flask uses sqlalchemy by default, so this [SQLAlchemy IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603088/sqlalchemy-in-clause) must answer your question

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```py
list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
all = Users.query.all() # get all users
users = [] # in the end, this list will store the users which have an id in the list

# loop through all the users
for user in all:
  if user.id in list:
    users.append(user) # if the user's id is in list append to list

# you now have a list of users in list stored in the variable users!
```